# How to hide the site name from browser tab?

Tags: 8

Is it possible to rewrite what is displayed in the browser's tabs. Fro example when I open some page, in the browser tab it is displayed as  "Page name | site_name". For example " About | site_name". And we would like to keep only the name of view page. Is it possible in Drupal 8 ?

Comment: You can configure title and a lot more meta tags with the https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag mdule.

Comment: As quex said, the metatag module is what you want.